# Why const names need to be wrapped in curly brackets in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
render () {
  const { params } = this.props.params
  return (
   <div>{ params.article }</div>
  )
}
```

Why does params need to be wrapped in curly brackets could it be just 'const params = this.props.params'

Comment: you are extracting params from this.props object

Comment: Got it, makes sense now, it's extract children of props

Answer (score 8):

This is called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Instead of doing

```
const params = this.props.params.params
```

you can use the short hand

```
const { params } = this.props.params.
```

See the examples

```js
const a = {
  key: 'value',
  key2: 'value2',
}

const {key} = a //getting a.key from a and assigning it to key

console.log(key)

const { key2: newVar } = a //getting a.key2 from a and assigning it to newVar

console.log(newVar)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, this is not a feature of React. It's a feature of Javascript.

Comment: @RobertWarrenGilmore Valid point!

Answer (score 5):

```
const { foo } = bar.baz
```

is the same as

```
const foo = bar.baz.foo
```

so what you're really doing there is setting `params` equal to `this.props.params.params`.

Also, this is not a feature of React. Rather, it's a feature of ES6 Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It is know as deconstructing assignment. You can extract the data or elements from objects or Arrays.

```
const { params } = this.props 
is same as
const params = this.props.params;
```

You can also pull the elements from the array

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const [a, b] = x // [1, 2];
```

At the end, it's your choice to use it or not.